# Make width of <a> to have a width equal to its content

Tags: css, web, width, html

In the first example below, the `id="A_2"` has a width equal to its content, while the one second, it `id="A_4"` has a width equal to its parent. How can I change the second snippet to have width equal to its content?

This snippet is from Google
[Play Store Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXvLwR)

```css
#H1_1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font-family: Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 39.2000007629395px;
    min-height: 37px;
    min-width: 680px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1088px;
    perspective-origin: 544px 37.5px;
    transform-origin: 544px 37.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 100 normal 28px/39.2000007629395px Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 248px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}/*#H1_1*/

#A_2 {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font-family: Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 39.2000007629395px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: normal normal 100 normal 28px/39.2000007629395px Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
}/*#A_2*/

#A_3 {
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    display: block;
    font-family: Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22.3999996185303px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 1078px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal; 16px/22.3999996185303px Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px 0px 4px;
}
```

```html
        <h1 id="H1_1">
  <a href="/store/apps/collection/promotion_3001315_cricket_worldcup_appsin" id="A_2">Cricket Fever</a> <a href="/store/apps/collection/promotion_3001315_cricket_worldcup_appsin" id="A_3">Get cool games + Cricket apps</a>
</h1>
```

Here is
[My Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPbRgN)

```css
#H1_1 {
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    min-height: 37px;
    min-width: 680px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1088px;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    font: normal normal bold normal 32px/normal Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 248px;
    padding: 5px;
}/*#H1_1*/

#A_2 {
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    height: 34px;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-self: stretch;
    border: 0px none rgb(85, 85, 85);
    font: normal normal 100 normal 28px/normal Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
}/*#A_2*/

#A_3 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    height: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-self: stretch;
    border: 0px none rgb(85, 85, 85);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px/normal Roboto, UILanguageFont, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 3px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 4px;
}/*#A_3*/
```

```html
<h1 id="H1_1">
  <a id="A_2" href="">Cricket Fever</a> <a id="A_3" href="">Get cool games + Cricket apps</a> 
</h1>
```

Comment: I see a width **1078** is given to A4, is it's with the purpose of bringing A4's content to new line?

Comment: even after removing width attribute its breadth is 100%

Comment: need to clean up that CSS code bud. You know you can merge half of that stuff together?

Comment: I actually used a tool to get that code from the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h1>` element has the same width as it content, or bigger if you define it.

There are inline elements and block elements. Inline elements a width equal to its content, the block elements use all the available width.
Since you defined 'A_4' as block, it will use all the available width.
Element `<a>` is an inline element, so it will have the same width as it content.

Remove the 'display:block' from the `<a>` elements, and all the fixed width or min-width values. To separate your link for different lines, separate then using `<br/>` element.

**EDIT:**
example:

HTML

```
<h1 id="H1_1">
     <a id="A_2" href="">Cricket Fever</a>
  <br/>
  <a id="A_3" href="">Get cool games + Cricket apps</a> 
</h1>
```

CSS

```
#H1_1 {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 248px;
    padding: 5px;
}/*#H1_1*/

#A_2 {
    background-color: #666;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    height: 34px;
    text-decoration: none;
}/*#A_2*/

#A_3 {
    background-color: #999;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 3px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 4px;
}/*#A_3*/
```

Comment: it seems to work only if I remove 'display:flex' from parent.Is there a way to make it work without having to remove 'display:flex' from parent?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want `a#A_4` to be as width as it's content... right?

Then remove the `display: block` from it.

To make the link appear on a new line, simply add a line break to it.

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNOzZV)

Comment: can u suggest what can I do in the code that I have written to do the same

Comment: I believe my answer already says what you should do... I even have updated your Codepen. What isn't clear about it?

Comment: I just wanted to know what changes do I have to do to my code,to get the result.And also I haven't used "display: block" attribute,but still it is 100% width.